# Should I remove or leave the plastic around the trunk of my new tree?

Tags: tree-care, planting, overwintering, pines

This tree arrived today to me via mail: (*Click on the pictures for larger view*.)

[image]
[image]

It is wrapped in several layers of plastic.

I plan to plant it in couple of days.

I will remove the plastic packaging around the root ball of course, but should I perhaps leave the packaging plastic around tree's trunk, just until spring? Is plastic an appropriate material that will help the tree overwinter?

The species is [Pinus pinea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_pine), also known as the stone pine, umbrella pine and parasol pine. It's actually a Mediterranean plant, and I am concerned about the possible negative impact of a harsh first winter to this beautiful plant.

I live in European zone 8, where the lower range is approximately −12.2 °C (10 °F).

The weather forecast for the whole winter this year is mild, but you never know.

Comment: Oh, you got it already! Did you get your “crooked” discount? ^_^

Comment: Yes, I did! I got this 180cm high tree for the price of 120cm high one! I did not get any discount on bananas though. :( @Stephie

Comment: @Stephie The crown (needles) has a wonderful fresh mild scent... Not mediteranian, but much milder, like grass... I am concerned a lot about root ball - it is small, and not that stable... I am a bit skeptical! :( The nursery guy told me to remove all plastic. And not to put any fertilizer into the planting hole...

Comment: My gut feeling is that something will go wrong - but it will still be a great experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't do any harm to keep the plastic around it.

However, plastic does not really insulate well. I would recommend wrapping it into several layers of cloth instead.

If you do think the tree won't survive the cold, go to your local farm shop and buy a bunch of tree bark to spread around its base, this will keep the cold from penetrating to the roots too much.